# SQL - Select if it contains string

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I'm trying to make an sql query which picks all the trucks with the **searchTerm in the name**

```
 $foodtrucks= DB::table('foodtrucks')
        ->rightjoin('users', 'foodtrucks.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->orderBy('users.premium_type','premium')
        ->select('foodtrucks.*')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', $searchTerm)
        ->orWhere('info', 'LIKE', $searchTerm)
        ->get();
```

I'm currently getting the results if I write te exact name but this is not what I want to happen, I want it to display the result even it the name contains the searchTerm

**so for example**

- I search "Truck"
- I get Truck123, Truck456 and Truck789

**What's happening now**

- I search "Truck"
- I get no results

---

- I search Truck123
- I get Truck123

Comment: Try changing : `->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are searching for `LIKE %Truck%`. Go for:

```
$foodtrucks= DB::table('foodtrucks')
        ->rightjoin('users', 'foodtrucks.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->orderBy('users.premium_type','premium')
        ->select('foodtrucks.*')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%")
        ->orWhere('info', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%")
        ->get();
```